# Write a prime module using file content in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module, primes

I have a file containing many prime numbers.

I'd like to write a module with the following functions:

```
module Primes as
( init,
  primes,
  is_prime)
where ...
```

where init should *read* the file and initialize the primes which should be a list and also is_prime.
My problem is, how should I write it? Isn't there a way to "hide" the IO monad?

More generally I believe I think like an OO programmer. What is the good functional way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to 'hide' the IO monad is to write `isPrime` (and any other functions that use the list of prime numbers) as a pure function, and only introduce IO as late as you possibly need. The fact that you are using a list of pregenerated prime numbers and reading them from a file is just an implementation detail that is irrelevant to general functions dealing with prime numbers.

Here's a simple implementation of a pure `isPrime` that takes an integer to test and a list of prime numbers. Notice that it doesn't care where the list of primes came from, just that it's a list of integers.

```
isPrime :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
isPrime n ps = n `elem` ps
```

Now let's introduce a function that will read the prime numbers from disk. Its return type must be in the IO monad because, well, we're performing I/O.

```
readPrimesFromFile :: String -> IO [Integer]
readPrimesFromFile filename = ...
```

Now we can use this function in combination with our `isPrime` function. Once we start using `readPrimesFromFile` we are forever 'trapped' in the IO monad.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    primeList <- readPrimesFromFile "primes.txt"
    let result = isPrime 123 primeList
    print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you start with a file of primes? The IO time to read the file is probably slower than just generating the primes from scratch.

See [Data.Numbers.Primes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/primes/latest/doc/html/Data-Numbers-Primes.html#v%3aprimes) for (afaik) the most efficient way to generate the list of all prime numbers.

Comment: I know it might be faster for prime. But I was also interrested for general cases where it is harder to generate. I think about tables used in many cryptographic algorithms. I am learning Haskell and really didn't know if it was possible to hide the monad inside a module.